# Interstitial Ads refused to compile after SDK upgrade

Tags: java

I got into trouble after updating Admob SDK to 19.8, my interstitial admanager got erros in setAdUnitId and loadAd. I have been going through the admob developers page to find replacement for the obsolete code but got confused the more.

I'm using AdManager so as to enable me show interstitial in the Recylerview onClickListener via NewActivity

This is the AdManager.java

```
public class AdsManager {
    private static InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private Context ctx;

    public AdsManager(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        MobileAds.initialize(ctx, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

            }
        });
    }
    public InterstitialAd createInterstitialAds(){
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(ctx);
        // Test Interstitial Ads = ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        return interstitialAd;
    }

    public InterstitialAd getInterstitialAd(){
        return interstitialAd;

    }

    public void createAds(AdView adView){

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ""+loadAdError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "ads is loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Refuse? What refuse?

Comment: After updating to  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0' gave me error code. Please help me correct